# What is the religion of Jinns?

Tags: jinn, religion

I wonder there is any authentic hadith regarding the religion of the Jinns? Since, as a rule, they ought to have a religion (s) for themselves, as Quran brings the name of Jin beside the name of Ens (human)...

Hence, what can be their religion(s)?

Comment: Two simple religions, the one in which they submit to Allah, and other in which they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would like to begin with the verses from the Qur'an, before mentioning any Hadith. Allah (SWT) talks about the Jinn in a Surah that was named after them, Surat Al-Jinn

> وَأَنَّا مِنَّا ٱلۡمُسۡلِمُونَ وَمِنَّا ٱلۡقَـٰسِطُونَ‌ۖ فَمَنۡ
> أَسۡلَمَ فَأُوْلَـٰٓٮِٕكَ تَحَرَّوۡاْ رَشَدً۬ا (١٤) وَأَمَّا
> ٱلۡقَـٰسِطُونَ فَكَانُواْ لِجَهَنَّمَ حَطَبً۬ا (١٥
>
> And there are among us some who have surrendered (to Allah) and there
> are among us some who are unjust. And whoso hath surrendered to Allah,
> such have taken the right path purposefully. (14) And as for those who are unjust, they are firewood for hell. (15)

Allah (SWT) also tells us in Surat Adh-dhariyat

> I created the jinn and humankind only that they might worship Me

The Jinns were created to worship Allah (SWT), just like mankind. So, they either surrender to Allah (SWT), or they disobey Him.

In Surat Al-Ahqaaf:

> And (recall) when We directed a group of Jinns towards you, listening
> to the Qur’an. 7 So, when they attended it, they said (to each other),
> “Keep quiet.” Then once it was over, they went back to their people as
> warners. (29) They said, “O our people, we have heard a book sent down
> after Musa, 8 confirming what was before it, which guides to the truth
> and to a straight path. (30) O our people, respond to Allah’s herald,
> and believe in him, and (once you do that,) Allah will forgive your
> sins for you, and will save you from a painful punishment. (31) The
> one who does not respond to Allah’s herald is not (able) to frustrate
> (Allah by escaping) in the land, and for him there are no supporters
> besides Him. Such people are in open error. (32)

Now, in the Hadith, the Prophet (PBUH) mentioned that he was sent to mankind and the Jinns. He (PBUH) also said in a hadith narrated by Muslim, that He (PBUH) was invited by one of the Jinns to go and recite Qur'an to his people.

> ‘Someone from among the jinn called me, and I went with him and
> recited Qur’aan for them.’

My understanding is, the Jinn either surrender to Allah (SWT) and follow the messenger of their time, like what they mentioned in Surat Al-Ahqaf about Prophet Musa (AS), or they disobey Allah (SWT). Therefore, those who followed the teachings of Prophet Musa (AS) are considered Jewish, and those who followed the teachings of Prophet Isa (AS) are considered Christians, and because Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) was sent to the entire universe, they are supposed to follow his teachings til the day of judgement.

*Indeed, Allah knows the best. Please forgive any ignorance in my answer.*

Comment: On the whole, it seems a nice answer with effort ... God  bless you dear mate.

Answer (score 1):

Jins are just like humans, they had their prophets that guided them through ages (Jin Prophets).

Allah [image: Swt] says:

> قُل لَّوْ كَانَ فِي الْأَرْضِ مَلَائِكَةٌ يَمْشُونَ مُطْمَئِنِّينَ لَنَزَّلْنَا عَلَيْهِم مِّنَ السَّمَاءِ مَلَكًا رَّسُولًا
>
> Say, "If there were upon the earth angels walking securely, We would have sent down to them from the heaven an angel [as a] messenger."
>
> [17:95](http://tanzil.net/#17:95)

The only prophet that is common between us and them, is the last prophet Mohammad [image: pbuh]

Qur'an Supports this:

> Say, [O Muhammad], "It has been revealed to me that a group of the
> jinn listened and said, 'Indeed, we have heard an amazing Qur'an. It
> guides to the right course, and we have believed in it. And we will
> never associate with our Lord anyone.
>
> [...]
>
> And among us are the righteous, and among us are [others] not so; we
> were [of] divided ways.
> [Al-Jinn](http://quran.com/72/1-11)

With no doubt they are treated like humans and some of them will go to hell:

> [Allah] will say, "Enter among nations which had passed on before you of *jinn and mankind into the Fire.*"[...]

Comment: it is relatively a good answer, but would you please name which religions they  have?

Comment: @salam when I say: *like humans* I don't mean that they look like humans, but that they have similar religions. Some are Jews, Christians, muslims ...

Comment: uh-huh, perhaps you are right, appropriate answer.